# How to stop slideshow moving on scroll

Tags: html, css

I have got a slideshow, below the header and on the right of the navigation menu, then i have got a sign in/out buttons, but both of them move up the page when the page gets scrolled down.

I have researched on here for a solution and even tried position: fixed. On the slideshow elements and the login/out elements but it just completely stops the page from being scrolled.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1><a href="index">Galaxy Games</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="active"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="games">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="videos">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="newswire">Newswire</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk" target="_blank">Social Club</a></li>
            <li><a href="downloads">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.galaxywarehouse.co.uk" target="_blank">Warehouse</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.support.galaxy-games.co.uk" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <global-login ng-version="6.0.7">
        <link href="galaxy_games/users/css/global-login.css" rel="stylesheet"><!---->
        <div class="logged-out">
            <div>
                <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_self">Sign In</a> or
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="sc" data-gtm-action="Join Social Club" data-gtm-category="Social Club" data-gtm-label="" href="#" target="_blank">Join Social Club</a>
            </div>
        </div><!---->
    </global-login>
</div>
<div class="info">
    <h1>Galaxy Games</h1>
    <h2>Home To The Great Unwashed Hordes</h2>
    <h3>EST Mcmxcviii</h3>
</div>
<div class="container show">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <a href="">
            <div class="icon icon-play"><!-- /c/ --></div>
            <img src="images/46e3dd55b6cc4f1df004cabd85cbaac6fc8e1218.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            </a>
                <a class="official" href="">Official Website</a></button>
                <a class="buy" href="">Buy Now</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="">
            <div class="icon icon-play"><!-- /c/ --></div>
            <img src="images/black.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            </a>
            <a class="official" href="">Official Website</a></button>
            <a class="buy" href="">Buy Now</a></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="">
            <div class="icon icon-play"><!-- /c/ --></div>
            <img src="images/46e3dd55b6cc4f1df004cabd85cbaac6fc8e1218.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            </a>
            <a class="official" href="">Official Website</a></button>
            <a class="buy" href="">Buy Now</a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.carousel{
    position:relative
}
.carousel-inner{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 690px;
    overflow:hidden
}
.carousel-inner>.item{
    position:relative;
    display:none;
    -webkit-transition:.6s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition:.6s ease-in-out left;
    transition:.6s ease-in-out left
}
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img,.carousel-inner>.item>img{
    line-height:1
}
.icon{
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden
}
.icon.icon-play{
    transition:opacity .2s;
    background-image:url(../images/global/home/play-icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50%;
    width:260px;
    height:200px;
    background-position:0 0;
    position:absolute;
    transform:translateY(-50%) scale(.5);
    opacity:.75;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-130px
}
@media all and (transform-3d),(-webkit-transform-3d){
    .carousel-inner>.item
    {
        -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition:-o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
        transition:-webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out;
        transition:transform .6s ease-in-out;
        transition:transform .6s ease-in-out,-webkit-transform .6s ease-in-out,-o-transform .6s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;
        -webkit-perspective:1000px;
        perspective:1000px
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item.active.right,.carousel-inner>.item.next{
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);
        transform:translate3d(100%,0,0);
        left:0
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item.active.left,.carousel-inner>.item.prev{
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);
        transform:translate3d(-100%,0,0);
        left:0
    }
    .carousel-inner>.item.active,.carousel-inner>.item.next.left,.carousel-inner>.item.prev.right{
        -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
        left:0
    }
}
.carousel-inner>.active,.carousel-inner>.next,.carousel-inner>.prev{
    display:block
}
.carousel-inner>.active{
    left:0
}
.carousel-inner>.next,.carousel-inner>.prev{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%
}
.carousel-inner>.next{
    left:100%
}
.carousel-inner>.prev{
    left:-100%
}
.carousel-inner>.next.left,.carousel-inner>.prev.right{
    left:0
}
.carousel-inner>.active.left{
    left:-100%
}
.carousel-inner>.active.right{
    left:100%
}
.carousel-control{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:15%;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:.5
}
.carousel-control.left{
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.5)),to(rgba(0,0,0,.0001)));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', 
        GradientType=1);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.carousel-control.right{
    right:0;
    left:auto;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right top,from(rgba(0,0,0,.0001)),to(rgba(0,0,0,.5)));
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,.0001) 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', 
        GradientType=1);
    background-repeat:repeat-x
}
.carousel-control:focus,.carousel-control:hover{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90);
    opacity:.9
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-control .icon-next,.carousel-control .icon-prev{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    z-index:5;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:-10px
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,.carousel-control .icon-prev{
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-10px
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,.carousel-control .icon-next{
    right:50%;
    margin-right:-10px
}
.carousel-control .icon-next,.carousel-control .icon-prev{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    font-family:serif;
    line-height:1
}
.carousel-control .icon-prev:before{
    content:"\2039"
}
.carousel-control .icon-next:before{
    content:"\203a"
}
.carousel-indicators{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:unset;
    top: 25px;
    left:80px;
    z-index:15;
    width:60%;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-left: -30%;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none
}
.carousel-indicators li{
    display:inline-block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    margin:1px;
    text-indent:-999px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#000\9;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius:10px
}
.carousel-indicators .active{
    margin-top: 250px;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#fff
}
.carousel-caption{
    position:absolute;
    right:15%;
    bottom:20px;
    left:15%;
    z-index:10;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6)
}
.carousel-caption h3{
    float:left;
    margin-left:-350px;
    background-color:#fff;
    padding: 7px 20px 5px;
    color:#000
}
.carousel-caption .btn{
    text-shadow:none
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
    .carousel-control .icon-next,.carousel-control .icon-prev
    {
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        margin-top:-10px;
        font-size:30px
    }
    .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,.carousel-control .icon-prev
    {
        margin-left:-10px
    }
    .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,.carousel-control .icon-next
    {
        margin-right:-10px
    }
    .carousel-caption
    {
        right:20%;
        left:20%;
        padding-bottom:30px
    }
    .carousel-indicators
    {
        bottom:20px
    }
}
body{
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:-25px;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical !important; 
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
.header{
    background-image: url(../images/black.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.header h1{
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.header h1 a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none
}
.header h1 a:hover{
    text-decoration: none
}
.menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    position:fixed;
}
.menu ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li a:hover{
    padding-bottom: 21px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff0000;
}
#active{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff0000
}
.menu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: -50%; /* or right 50% */
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.info{
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 180px;
    width: 100%
}
.info h1{
    color: #fff;
    font-size:10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.info h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    right: -43%; /* or right 50% */
    text-align: left;
    margin-top:-20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.info h3{
    color: #fff;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
.show{
    margin-top: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: none;
    overflow-x: hidden
}
.official{
    float: right;
    margin-right:-170px;
    padding: 6px 35px 4px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border:1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 75ms linear;
    color:#ff0000;
    font-family: DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
}
.official:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255);
    border:1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 75ms linear;
    color:#ff0000;
    font-family: DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none
}
.buy{
    float: right;
    margin-right:-310px;
    padding: 6px 35px 4px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border:1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 75ms linear;
    color:#ff0000;
    font-family: DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
}
.buy:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255);
    border:1px solid #fff;
    transition: all 75ms linear;
    color:#ff0000;
    font-family: DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none
}
@font-face{
    font-family:DINNext-Bld;
    src:url(../fonts/DINNext-bold.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/DINNext-bold.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
    url(../fonts/DINNext-bold.woff) format("woff"),
    url(../fonts/DINNext-bold.ttf) format("truetype"),
    url(../img/_/fonts/DINNext-bold.svg#) format("svg")
}
@font-face{
    font-family:DINNext-Med;
    src:url(../fonts/DINNext-Med.eot);
    src:url(../fonts/DINNext-Med.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
    url(../fonts/DINNext-Med.woff) format("woff"),
    url(../fonts/DINNext-Med.ttf) format("truetype"),
    url(../img/_/fonts/DINNext-Med.svg#) format("svg")
}
.font-next-bld{
    font-family:DINNext-Bld,sans-serif
}
.font-next-med{
    font-family:
    DINNext-Med,sans-serif
}
global-login{
    font-size:10px;
    display:block;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:5;
    font-family:DINNext-Bld,sans-serif;
    font-weight:400 !important;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    height:50px;
}
global-login a{
    text-decoration:none
}
global-login .logged-out{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    background:#000;
    font-family:DINNext-Med,sans-serif;
    color:#777;
    line-height:1.3em;
    text-align:right;
    padding:5px;
    position:fixed;
    right:20px;
    top:18%;
    transform:
    translateY(-50%);
    min-width:100px
}
global-login .logged-out a{
    color:#fff !important;
    font-weight:400
}
global-login .logged-out div:last-child a{
    color:#00adf0 !important
}
global-login .logged-out>div{
    width:-webkit-max-content;
    width:-moz-max-content;
    width:max-content;
    flex-basis:100%
}
global-login .logged-in{
    position:relative;
    max-width:50px;
    width:700px;
    transition:max-width .2s
}
global-login .logged-in .top{
    padding:9px;display:flex
}
global-login .logged-in .top .avatar{
    transition:background .2s;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:100%;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    flex-shrink:0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5
}
global-login .logged-in .top .avatar .activity-count{
    transition:left right .2s;
    background:red;
    padding:0 2px;
    display:inline;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:1.3
}
global-login .logged-in .top .nickname{
    align-self:center;
    font-family:DINNext-Bld,sans-serif;
    z-index:4;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 10px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity .2s;
    font-size:1.3em
}
global-login .logged-in.links-active{
    background:gray;
    max-width:200px
}
global-login .logged-in.links-active .top .nickname{
    opacity:1
}
global-login .logged-in.links-active .links{
    display:flex
}
global-login .logged-in .links{
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    text-align:left;
    display:none;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    color:#000;width:100%
}
global-login .logged-in .links a{
    flex:0 0 100%;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width:-webkit-max-content;
    min-width:-moz-max-content;
    min-width:max-content;
    color:inherit;
    display:block;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    line-height:1;
    padding:15px;
    font-family:DINNext-Med,sans-serif
}
global-login .logged-in .links a:hover{
    background:#ddd
}
global-login .logged-in .links a:before{
    content:"";
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAADgCAYAAACzdWAwAAAKQ2lDQ1BJQ0MgcHJvZmlsZQAAeNqdU3dYk/cWPt/3ZQ9WQtjwsZdsgQAiI6wIyBBZohCSAGGEEBJAxYWIClYUFRGcSFXEgtUKSJ2I4qAouGdBiohai1VcOO4f3Ke1fXrv7e371/u855zn/M55zw+AERImkeaiagA5UoU8Otgfj09IxMm9gAIVSOAEIBDmy8JnBcUAAPADeXh+dLA//AGvbwACAHDVLiQSx+H/g7pQJlcAIJEA4CIS5wsBkFIAyC5UyBQAyBgAsFOzZAoAlAAAbHl8QiIAqg0A7PRJPgUA2KmT3BcA2KIcqQgAjQEAmShHJAJAuwBgVYFSLALAwgCgrEAiLgTArgGAWbYyRwKAvQUAdo5YkA9AYACAmUIszAAgOAIAQx4TzQMgTAOgMNK/4KlfcIW4SAEAwMuVzZdL0jMUuJXQGnfy8ODiIeLCbLFCYRcpEGYJ5CKcl5sjE0jnA0zODAAAGvnRwf44P5Dn5uTh5mbnbO/0xaL+a/BvIj4h8d/+vIwCBAAQTs/v2l/l5dYDcMcBsHW/a6lbANpWAGjf+V0z2wmgWgrQevmLeTj8QB6eoVDIPB0cCgsL7SViob0w44s+/zPhb+CLfvb8QB7+23rwAHGaQJmtwKOD/XFhbnauUo7nywRCMW735yP+x4V//Y4p0eI0sVwsFYrxWIm4UCJNx3m5UpFEIcmV4hLpfzLxH5b9CZN3DQCshk/ATrYHtctswH7uAQKLDljSdgBAfvMtjBoLkQAQZzQyefcAAJO/+Y9AKwEAzZek4wAAvOgYXKiUF0zGCAAARKCBKrBBBwzBFKzADpzBHbzAFwJhBkRADCTAPBBCBuSAHAqhGJZBGVTAOtgEtbADGqARmuEQtMExOA3n4BJcgetwFwZgGJ7CGLyGCQRByAgTYSE6iBFijtgizggXmY4EImFINJKApCDpiBRRIsXIcqQCqUJqkV1II/ItchQ5jVxA+pDbyCAyivyKvEcxlIGyUQPUAnVAuagfGorGoHPRdDQPXYCWomvRGrQePYC2oqfRS+h1dAB9io5jgNExDmaM2WFcjIdFYIlYGibHFmPlWDVWjzVjHVg3dhUbwJ5h7wgkAouAE+wIXoQQwmyCkJBHWExYQ6gl7CO0EroIVwmDhDHCJyKTqE+0JXoS+cR4YjqxkFhGrCbuIR4hniVeJw4TX5NIJA7JkuROCiElkDJJC0lrSNtILaRTpD7SEGmcTCbrkG3J3uQIsoCsIJeRt5APkE+S+8nD5LcUOsWI4kwJoiRSpJQSSjVlP+UEpZ8yQpmgqlHNqZ7UCKqIOp9aSW2gdlAvU4epEzR1miXNmxZDy6Qto9XQmmlnafdoL+l0ugndgx5Fl9CX0mvoB+nn6YP0dwwNhg2Dx0hiKBlrGXsZpxi3GS+ZTKYF05eZyFQw1zIbmWeYD5hvVVgq9ip8FZHKEpU6lVaVfpXnqlRVc1U/1XmqC1SrVQ+rXlZ9pkZVs1DjqQnUFqvVqR1Vu6k2rs5Sd1KPUM9RX6O+X/2C+mMNsoaFRqCGSKNUY7fGGY0hFsYyZfFYQtZyVgPrLGuYTWJbsvnsTHYF+xt2L3tMU0NzqmasZpFmneZxzQEOxrHg8DnZnErOIc4NznstAy0/LbHWaq1mrX6tN9p62r7aYu1y7Rbt69rvdXCdQJ0snfU6bTr3dQm6NrpRuoW623XP6j7TY+t56Qn1yvUO6d3RR/Vt9KP1F+rv1u/RHzcwNAg2kBlsMThj8MyQY+hrmGm40fCE4agRy2i6kcRoo9FJoye4Ju6HZ+M1eBc+ZqxvHGKsNN5l3Gs8YWJpMtukxKTF5L4pzZRrmma60bTTdMzMyCzcrNisyeyOOdWca55hvtm82/yNhaVFnMVKizaLx5balnzLBZZNlvesmFY+VnlW9VbXrEnWXOss623WV2xQG1ebDJs6m8u2qK2brcR2m23fFOIUjynSKfVTbtox7PzsCuya7AbtOfZh9iX2bfbPHcwcEh3WO3Q7fHJ0dcx2bHC866ThNMOpxKnD6VdnG2ehc53zNRemS5DLEpd2lxdTbaeKp26fesuV5RruutK10/Wjm7ub3K3ZbdTdzD3Ffav7TS6bG8ldwz3vQfTw91jicczjnaebp8LzkOcvXnZeWV77vR5Ps5wmntYwbcjbxFvgvct7YDo+PWX6zukDPsY+Ap96n4e+pr4i3z2+I37Wfpl+B/ye+zv6y/2P+L/hefIW8U4FYAHBAeUBvYEagbMDawMfBJkEpQc1BY0FuwYvDD4VQgwJDVkfcpNvwBfyG/ljM9xnLJrRFcoInRVaG/owzCZMHtYRjobPCN8Qfm+m+UzpzLYIiOBHbIi4H2kZmRf5fRQpKjKqLupRtFN0cXT3LNas5Fn7Z72O8Y+pjLk722q2cnZnrGpsUmxj7Ju4gLiquIF4h/hF8ZcSdBMkCe2J5MTYxD2J43MC52yaM5zkmlSWdGOu5dyiuRfm6c7Lnnc8WTVZkHw4hZgSl7I/5YMgQlAvGE/lp25NHRPyhJuFT0W+oo2iUbG3uEo8kuadVpX2ON07fUP6aIZPRnXGMwlPUit5kRmSuSPzTVZE1t6sz9lx2S05lJyUnKNSDWmWtCvXMLcot09mKyuTDeR55m3KG5OHyvfkI/lz89sVbIVM0aO0Uq5QDhZML6greFsYW3i4SL1IWtQz32b+6vkjC4IWfL2QsFC4sLPYuHhZ8eAiv0W7FiOLUxd3LjFdUrpkeGnw0n3LaMuylv1Q4lhSVfJqedzyjlKD0qWlQyuCVzSVqZTJy26u9Fq5YxVhlWRV72qX1VtWfyoXlV+scKyorviwRrjm4ldOX9V89Xlt2treSrfK7etI66Trbqz3Wb+vSr1qQdXQhvANrRvxjeUbX21K3nShemr1js20zcrNAzVhNe1bzLas2/KhNqP2ep1/XctW/a2rt77ZJtrWv913e/MOgx0VO97vlOy8tSt4V2u9RX31btLugt2PGmIbur/mft24R3dPxZ6Pe6V7B/ZF7+tqdG9s3K+/v7IJbVI2jR5IOnDlm4Bv2pvtmne1cFoqDsJB5cEn36Z8e+NQ6KHOw9zDzd+Zf7f1COtIeSvSOr91rC2jbaA9ob3v6IyjnR1eHUe+t/9+7zHjY3XHNY9XnqCdKD3x+eSCk+OnZKeenU4/PdSZ3Hn3TPyZa11RXb1nQ8+ePxd07ky3X/fJ897nj13wvHD0Ivdi2yW3S609rj1HfnD94UivW2/rZffL7Vc8rnT0Tes70e/Tf/pqwNVz1/jXLl2feb3vxuwbt24m3Ry4Jbr1+Hb27Rd3Cu5M3F16j3iv/L7a/eoH+g/qf7T+sWXAbeD4YMBgz8NZD+8OCYee/pT/04fh0kfMR9UjRiONj50fHxsNGr3yZM6T4aeypxPPyn5W/3nrc6vn3/3i+0vPWPzY8Av5i8+/rnmp83Lvq6mvOscjxx+8znk98ab8rc7bfe+477rfx70fmSj8QP5Q89H6Y8en0E/3Pud8/vwv94Tz+4A5JREAAAAZdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEltYWdlUmVhZHlxyWU8AAADJmlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPD94cGFja2V0IGJlZ2luPSLvu78iIGlkPSJXNU0wTXBDZWhpSHpyZVN6TlRjemtjOWQiPz4gPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iQWRvYmUgWE1QIENvcmUgNS42LWMwNjcgNzkuMTU3NzQ3LCAyMDE1LzAzLzMwLTIzOjQwOjQyICAgICAgICAiPiA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPiA8cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIiB4bWxuczp4bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8iIHhtbG5zOnhtcE1NPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvbW0vIiB4bWxuczpzdFJlZj0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wL3NUeXBlL1Jlc291cmNlUmVmIyIgeG1wOkNyZWF0b3JUb29sPSJBZG9iZSBQaG90b3Nob3AgQ0MgMjAxNSAoV2luZG93cykiIHhtcE1NOkluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6NTJCMkJGRTZCQTQxMTFFNTlFMkFGODU0RjdFRDNCQjEiIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6NTJCMkJGRTdCQTQxMTFFNTlFMkFGODU0RjdFRDNCQjEiPiA8eG1wTU06RGVyaXZlZEZyb20gc3RSZWY6aW5zdGFuY2VJRD0ieG1wLmlpZDo1MkIyQkZFNEJBNDExMUU1OUUyQUY4NTRGN0VEM0JCMSIgc3RSZWY6ZG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDo1MkIyQkZFNUJBNDExMUU1OUUyQUY4NTRGN0VEM0JCMSIvPiA8L3JkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4gPC9yZGY6UkRGPiA8L3g6eG1wbWV0YT4gPD94cGFja2V0IGVuZD0iciI/PmyKNd8AABMESURBVHja7F19jFXFFb+zIBS1q9VVsCkoSkHxIwSwJgjaP4jEGBaJxtioyRJLoulSG/+gMa3LHyrwD2qDSpMSbUyaaiQRjbG7GMMqSDClQBF2+RBEkHWjsvK5dIG903N457Lz7puZe2buvY/dfW+Ss3ff3LkzZ353Zs7HzJ0RUsqgkkNNUOnBswW8ALQNaDvQSJ8ytYT3DBTq418A2ga0HWik7XktYd09AVDz6SwHAAaSCnX6AODTBf5I1z1AZ3xaQEZBy4fMsAs8p4l7mso4BtQO1Ea/TwM9FEv7DFBLBi3gOU3c0/TWjwG1A7XR79NAD8XSPgPU4toF1HQLgF5Sfp+k/r+TaLtyD9/EMqANStwmFwBCcxNfAPSS8vsk9f+dRNvDvntngJbB7w34m+I36QAQ5/4IofJ3FKgW6CugsUr8/4C+pmeFBrChQOOUOHx+ONDPgX4PtDyx1aXkAysrHPhAWIZq2Oiigs/QG45XVhi6zFmgXQogGC6m63aPUbYLCqrFtymYfAgPPnSD4G/oemUsE7WciwikWnrzwsAgDkyfA611BUAQHyJnPnQtYCPQ90BXAf2gZILd8ydA11FcL9AQ5f+9lCbORLOLbFUe3Ai/vxc586EbAyJeugiIKOMrgEYBddDovp8A/CXQ/cTUPpIIUYYTgLqBLmFJHgsfBM45PuD/USIlH7JQeS0zr9H9dqKdVAjGbQW6RcP6PSQaMc1uegaf/ZLipnuIwddoBG8nUYcj/X4a5bcC3aIRbfeQaMQ0u+kZfPZLipueJAVGEFI9SqUFIXgYqM7SgicC7aDW8qXSZ2+k663RIMRoAc58KN1nIvy/QzD4CBRNcA4l7Fa0q6jPXUr/NyZ0YVSK/kb9sUZ5/gv6/wsq4xFLHs58yFKR0CZifEgLH1ELiPL5EegQ0DAl73GUmWCMY3U0bnSSHBfKGIKi6FpUjKDM27WDIPAhPPmIDaAsPqAF3B4Xg9/RgKK2USz0IHMgj0brizS89dDvkxbR582H8OQjAqBDGS2HxwpGzWs0E4Cf0fWEUmhI8eMpbp/l+RI+ZM58RAD8AWgNjdxjSZREDx5U0iSF9+jao7yYK0gR+QzoX0AvW54v4UN48CFd+IiNyLU0yqpisI0GJUl9xxSeojQHFENpF8WtdxSDqAIfJtHVrlh83RR3rcVR8hSlOaAYSrsobn3Rcxp/AMryv8T6Tw2Jk4BE0p81lf8nIYpN7rimKS5w0Qa5fMStIenAh2BogqEihgLSrG5QDIsuYupypf8eUdTSqC//G+hXKTRBZz7goSOCwYfJGsSwDmhGTLoMo+aNhV1DfSoacbso7RCNVPomhdfHiw/hwIeuBYwjxH+IGSEGkWv0D0QWJRozk4G2OLaAXPiAiC1CaQE6c/h9pUkPIUfCdSQZpMUul2RsTCBRM1Rh/BWPt/++ZPAhHfkQDJ/g47GB9TtFH4/EURuN8Lvo/w7l/jaSHmoe0zyMocdjLrHv0BhS3F4HSTLsIsL/O6L0YcFd1q78xus0rk/wHUqzg/RztPbepMpLUlPbiDopbie96SlAU8mvgPGLUjhF36EK7ACaQ9bem1R5jD9EFW8jt7gksfcK0BSgqbLgV8D4Ra7zAk1Ak2JxqIl9pJi9u+n/ZtLc1IA6wwMZeIWbgCbF4kbDG/0oMnvDgumLb7kZrsNjOgLqDA9kOTFyvSavay/AxMj1sS5SpCDlPTP0jZLPgQs1MwRv+Bul8gecp9YsekBSmAt0H+XbckHmNB35EDFZGV1FdXq8wkMVgCoAlR5oELw3ps7mRVjGvRYxeK+qzsYpNMQn3dfEd0jiIwKgHJU/D4IFgA6ZUMk0FMZBUCZGZJlbnTCYw+4LPJj+egMjYsCPAcKsJA3OQVAy4sRgBcDU3EWKPGsGenN3aSm6+zX9vXnnBZbojwCIHAEZkF3Ap8nLwTwGSAZYwjGfQTEIyhT5DApjqGLEYEWawzInkSkHAgA2Q0dklO+AEIMcESc9QR00UkB4ghoB8G0Z62H7xOZbX7XWQxR2qgD8NvD49scj4KTq45b73nwITz5MS2SyUsz0D/KXyGTCh7GLpJgaizLfD3RZ0Lc+J+Ww7yHcCm9PzwflZ4M1TQtQ38BRYiBdC/B6DaJQ0YI/sZgPk+8xYykgqNCdF0ZZkGplnfkYmtV7KJP5bm8FCIKjZzlLPQBB+PqCgtDXEth8ZDEGOOsluU/JCxr8GWNAdX1A1RyuAlDZYWifMmUN+B3Br4PCik9cO4hLUEcpxg2uF8RP6vCj6dagsNw9D1U4Uz4CxjI5/PiokTLjTn+30jN1NgBsy+Q0S9rqgBqBWh2mw1vpmTrfdYKzgN4N/NcBvEt5sAEwbJMxC+hdzzUAkp6dpV03aAGgIShd8OxD7ZSXUwtQqEFd8MxZKWK41055sVpAA9nLWa0IORQHgbmBQgMthnZeKqOmUdIeKgFBA8CsjN68riXMcmgBs3RvXnquEYq1hFmhAYA6bp8/duyYPHr06Pmrw5hQxwCgjtvnsXyVElqAOibU6XaReTgofH7OsED77AcHO+J+KiMpnONDenh8mS6pIj5qFPn6oIsTJmo5jrbEg1SWTc4/GLev05hqIoGPCABULu5290QFrpbk3VSWKRTxIRgt0eUFSA0fEQDT/Jwx0se0neZ5L7E1OraGaapHaJKf2e3VOCdx79m+i5OeIMTLilrAeN8W4BHGc+/ZPgoUSsU9nTrjVQBG+TZ9DxBG+dwTCdIozoc09/+isrzN4YzdaC4DGIsf265LUuMVRlNyLJeZ1tbWPodCjTOGnQn3xnJbwJDWTwJRA3dCt1YoFD4iAHa7ALBgwYIgDEOfykdl2e6x+RixoBFUvTDAFc/nVD7DmzaMJbvVLrDVt2kiEI5hq8s93rutMTb7+ISFiJUVtYANLjVYvnx50e85c+a4PL7B815JOLX8lUIXoHDx7Nn8ARTKEsroWevi9YmMj8ggcvQW1VqModokr0+oMYaQDySuhQhxrSHxEXUB9J2tchWFHpJgVYKfLpEPodFDbHwYVpevEsSHOoq9BbTaRQFy1AFWUxlJIZEP6amOSx0fg8khwmj67UX+wf7oElOcllqXWOjvGWK5xAaEU5QLRNwpGvZ3t7jMwC0umW5x7v4BZZ8Y0c0NhBlNjOhaAHd9wICaGiMlhzU1Vl0fEFR4qAJQBaAKQBWAig6cL1KkIoNvJScKbp70lZIGt9iaGRT2HMPdG3HrvLdt3p8S8avXAbLnw1HsRy1kHtCnQWGryh7S8ZcEhR2gMTwbGLbLYGuDdvWyhq7zgD4FOgHUQzr+EqARdP9ZadguQ50SV4kTVlp4w53ccaNC3PzwR0OaSRkAgLTSYgjtBboKaBzQjwbDaZIPAPMYuv/nlPZRw/21GQAwj2EFfk5pHzWkW+sDwHGmAXQnpe/S3MMuc7UvANR0jzOdIHfSc12aFoBd5up4uTYpgFtSXsocKx6l638093AT1F+kGKXZfIjC2y/hQ1j4sAFwgwOf19HVtIPsadeKS08+hCMfWekBUT66WRLsFl+7Vt5zMwVnPmwAdDjwHCGum91dFxTv8uyqnHSocQlrhzLjIzrBhesFig5N2K+5NzWFFMDvXy5y8Ac+Qs/t19yb6iIFIsA/YAKAWtmNmvhlvopQ2AcAXj9gusGGAt2oiV/mqwiNZlT+OWXWR43fmuQWc9ADRjNc4NGZZKtiabbG/YCummCThbc2SnOHYT5gZkYAnNte17JbXBu94TsM8wEz0wCA4TMNT72KfN5r4f0ToPnxgclzR9nPNGNAL9CldH+vZXz4BGg+nlHkCgDu4L7ZAEC9YqE9QQaTiX+0FV4M6MtOR00Q6RqgzZqK9UKaeuVghifIYDK1FrQVXgS6LAkAfLvPA51KeDE40aieGnMT0IeW9Lhj/DUOLQDf7vNApxIGwLegcrcrz90E9KEl/R5ZeLklYS7JTNeZIDy05AVFt3jYknajbVKErnOB1oXuM0H76CzSGsrrYUvajWrFb6ORO+18IB5f8yTlOTMwfq1i/FzmNhy5w/Qzwngg45OU70zTM9ESGTw/7L8ZqcV49MVrZHj8Ceh3NEd4XDGOThjU31sE8eGzCC+2e7QTH5uCIJf9Qyc6isFNKWeBTTTRJAajczqm5ORzrHdIq+Ujo8/SjXxgFzhLSgvuvnAmo4pHB50ddHjGyEeKNalDcDAUtiO6qpOj1YmRKgBVAKoAVHLwsI3RrF0Y9B20tDBgfnFiXBzFMIzC0t+j4LoQD1kKCwctLZSFONbpMufrzAQA5TouxV5NMjqe5xm6NzsoPuUtMwCIUK7PBlpNB6zHNb4zdG82pU0NAM75LQ7ctt/voGfGZQgAzvktdtx+v4OeGecKAM74PkZzemltgbWU1wgPAHDG9zGa00trC2Aej4XRLLIFgFeDwqGJWRtFmOerDgC8iocmctcCh3wD6oiM8VGkCud90IJkbGxEjMikmaI0s0zqBksDQgwKRiWl57M1mvmzvEJXTmnPfxzlk3ccgEM5AnAop7TGVmH4fWjAAMA5ToPbbRR3mRWA9hwBaHdNm+Y4DcuY0G4DYEuOAGzJI63H4LfFBsDmHAHY7FApdlqPY3Y2G11ioAegHo8bk16SceVxrgCnonqZekBmfMQ2XTgpcGpO4SPeAvBGaw5vv5Xy5gac8GxN2w3iLURo+NApQs05AOCcp3B4RqThQ2MMcRZFuNJoF2OIbP/RaXeO0twfHTLN4fUZVn59CnN4fRazQ2GB1uvMYZMt8EaGzf/1FJrcG45N3KYqv64dLwwtANcGHM7g7R8OlFWeHi0A1wYczmC+8LCyioTVAnDWdEUGb39FoJkJdghaPkSWfFhcYlemdI4coTzSusSutDlHGHSE8ghcWkBAzXdJire3hPJIa83ly0eCUxRXi27zePvb6NmsnKK4WnSbR9/fRs8Wu9Yd3eI4Z9/jUPmewLDeIKVbfAqt+edWvoee0X407TovMN8BgPk5zgvMd5AG87OcGMGwlFH5pVnPDGk+p1/KEItLs54ZisJiS76L85waiwGy2PLmF+cxNaaGhtiY0BNotsnIC4DY9ho9sT7fYNqEIUsAMOB3PB8TTXCYF3Axhjg0AehjoglsMWWaGKnEUF0gUekADKjzBXA5vEjBR8k8YX8/X0AZDCvjfAGD8lOykVLo5hPw2kipIbhAW2mFQckW+5lspRUq+4iFwQDYTE16bqYWmlvJ4D9fgLmpmnE7vbqUfb6s5wuEgfe+gkXnC6gANNoqMGPGDFZFE9I1MgBotFbqrrt4bxv4sNxvjANg3VS1paVFhmEom5qarJXH+5gO0wcem6qGSZuqrlkjoQAJBdkrj/cxHaY3i8haFYB6TsVsIHDSENVbWkC9tYlHFUNa1GSvfDJQ9SoAic4OWwUdKn/OaWIBYGliHzdUMHSrfMFpogDQzOnfuoritbe3l1t5pGYLAM2s/q2rqFvlpSQ+IgD2cUdzFYQ10Mcc3vz5DywtAOxjj/aLFvVVGMacvq6xiCsh9qkAdLuItAgEDI6VR+q2ANDtMNnZ99YLjCS++Rgw3UkTI/0mSP1kp9ckaUme/bELhK7jgNoFeP2/pAukGgQdQch8EORKgJh90NyvxaCRFlFFQfKUVJQpCUKNGOx3ipC3ktNkAciiCFlV4aivc1VhTO+jCieeLxD1da4qjOmZqnCiMXQXGCGccSIhXXpjSDFyQpuoczSGBpw5zFGWQrOLrK5fOkRCg0MkzMAvwDlwcUC4xFIslRtc5wt4uMIaBoxbvKLPFzCQ18RIyJgYGZTnCyAfCIConi9QnR3OBwDoMsOA/gp0imgFxpWNaywLygc6RbQi8C2fvW6neCnNUicrL2vSW41e5ft2gbmauPvL2HIzK98XAN3urCfKCEBm5fsC8LIm7qUyApBZ+d5iEAa9OYqa+3fI572yDt+x8gPP8p0BgIrjVtc/NTVNyG9vzhW3lh+4lu84+t8cFDY9M2mXeG9ijqP/zUBnLervWelYvisALQxboCVHAFoYNkBLLgAkOU5jNDuHytc7GEKzMwUgKGw/uccBAEw7LMPKD6NdYLkA7JHM8rli8KlAsy+QJYyjZ7IK+ZXPePsjybx1dYjgMyMzePsjgY55OEKOSUb5HADUU2Y2MyquplmZAQArlUptZlRcTbMyFQAQJscWbk5nADAjKP7AY3KKyk+WhaPVowpNZwAwQ/k/lAnlJwGg7jD9FsUlfItwLs3bSty6FACsU7fOpjg7AIU0bytx69IA0EaVwP3FxzgAMCbo25O8LQUAbVQJ3Fd8jAMAY5S9yK3lW1VhUHuHk4OzE9L9g+JkwqAqKN0j5K9bDnGnPdXe8+UHVH6QtN1XtE2WUn5gKd/HFmABkKMtwAOgDD7BbnJMzKX/yx0yKT9NCzgKz15Ocfil+GVlbgFHAyo/UMovZwuousWrAFQBqAJQBaAKQBWAygPgCF07lbjO2L08Q6blV/z6gP8LMACihMwhRQk48wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==");
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    background-size:32px auto;
    margin-right:5px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a span.count{
    color:red
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.hasNew.messages:before{
    background-position:-17px -16px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.hasNew.notifications:before{
    background-position:-17px -32px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.hasNew.friendrequests:before{
    background-position:-17px -48px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.hasNew.crewinvites:before{
    background-position:-17px -64px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.hasNew a,global-login .logged-in .links a.hasNew a span{
    color:red !important;
    text-shadow:none !important
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.profile:before{
    background-position:0 -96px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.messages:before{
    background-position:0 -16px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.notifications:before{
    background-position:0 -32px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.friendrequests:before{
    background-position:0 -48px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.crewinvites:before{
    background-position:0 -64px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a.logout:before{
    background-position:0 -80px
}
global-login .logged-in .links a:not(:last-child){
    border-bottom:1px solid #d9d9d9
}
global-login .logged-in .links a:hover{
    background:#dfdfdf;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

Screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z57SD.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: So what do you want to happen? Whats the issue? It's hard to understand what your issue is - it would be easier if you could supply a StackSnippet that reproduces the issue, as well as explain what you would like to happen.

Comment: @MattOestreich I want the login/out and the slideshow not to move up the page when you scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little messed. You have several ending tags for div and button but no starting tags. Also you should not create a link inside another link. As a solution for your code, changing the position of .carousel element from relative into fixed, should do just fine.

```
.carousel {
    position:fixed;
}
```